# C++ class that accepts function of any type as parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, implementation

I'm writing a .hpp file for a class that should receive a function as one of it's parameters and store it in a member variable, so far my code looks like this:

```
template<typename Function> class myClass
{
  public:
           myClass(Function function) : pvFunction( function ) {}

           //Functor operator
           double operator() (double x) const{
             return pvFunction(x+4);
           }
  private:
           Function pvFunction
}
```

The program looks pointless because it is, the values it returns are not important for now. I'm simply trying to figure out how to pass a function to this class and use its functor operator.  The only problems are:

1) I don't know if this class definition is correct, meaning is this the proper way of accepting any type of function to be passed as a parameter to an object of this class.

2) how do I create an instance of this class in my program? how do I pass the function to the new object and then call it?

Been at this for quite some time and can't seem to figure it out

EDIT:

in my program file, main.cpp, this code receives an error:

```
double function(double);

int main()
{
   myClass<double> myClassObject((function));
   return 0;
}

double function(double x)
{
   return (x+3.0);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of [`boost::function<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function.html) for inspiration.

Comment: Do you really mean "any type" or "any type matching a certain parameter type list and return type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes it is.

2) The Type of `myClassObject` from your example should be

```
 myClass<double(*)(double)> myClassObject(function);
```

since function is of type `double(*)(double)`. The best way to construct objects of such a template, is to use a function template like this:

```
template<typename Function>
myClass<Function> MakeMyClass(Function f)
{
    return myClass<Function>(f);
}


int main()
{
   auto withFuncPtr= MakeMyClass(function);
   auto withLambda= MakeMyClass([] (double v) {return v*2;});

   Foo foo;
   auto withStdFunction = MakeMyClass(
       std::bind(&Foo::Method, &foo, std::placeholders::_1));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You get an error because the class expects the template parameter to be the actual function type, but you pass the template parameter as `double` in the instantiation.

Consider to use the new functionality of C++11 like [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```
template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
    typedef std::function<T(T)> func_type;

    func_type pvFunction;

    myClass(func_type func) : pvFunction(func) {}

    T operator()(T x)
        { return pvFunction(x + 4); }
};

double function(double x)
{
    return (x+3.0);
}

int main()
{
    myClass<double> my_class(function);
    std::cout << "my_class(3) = " << my_class(3) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: interesting, this would definitely be more convenient

Answer (score 0):

You can use struct with operator() as suggestion

```
template<typename Function> class myClass
{
  public:
        myClass(){}

        //Functor operator
        double operator() (double x) const
        {
          return pvFunction(x+4);
        }
  private:
        Function pvFunction;
};

struct Double
{
    double operator()(const double n)const
    {
        return n;
    }
};

int main() {
    myClass<Double> myClassObject;
    std::cout<<myClassObject(2.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you want to achieve, since how can you use any function if you still want to bind it to having an argument type of double, but, the example below makes your example template work, but i really don't see the use.

```
    template<typename Function> class myClass
    {
    public:
        myClass(Function function) : pvFunction( function ) {}

        //Functor operator
        double operator() (double x) const{
            return pvFunction(x+4);
        }
    private:
        Function pvFunction;
    };

    double foo1(double x)
    {
        return x;
    }

    double foo2(double x)
    {
        return x + 1;
    }
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        myClass<double(*)(double)> instance1(foo1);
        myClass<double(*)(double)> instance2(foo2);
        double a = instance1(1.5), b = instance2(1.5);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Eventually this will become a derivative class, but I need to be able to store the function to derive first. I didn't want people giving suggestions for how to implement a class that takes the derivative of a function so I left that tidbit of info out.